# How to asynchronously update dynamically generated HTML control in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

I have a method `getTextContent` that will be called indirectly through a user's click (method `getTextContent` is passed to an API function that registers it with some event).

The method returns a string that is simply a string of HTML, that is then displayed to the user in an API generated control.

What I would like to do is asynchronously update one of the HTML controls. I believe I can create a uniqueID and name that HTML control with that ID for alter reference.

My hangup is this: How do I pass the unique ID to the return/success method (`SucceededCallback`) of the webservice.

```
Webservice1.Foo(param1, SucceededCallback, FailedCallback);
```

so that I have a function like

```
function SucceededCallback(result, uniqueID) {
   document.getElementById(uniqueID).value = result;
}
```

I suppose I could create a global variable, but that seems improper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the context to the function.

```
Webservice1.Foo(param1, SucceededCallback.bind(uniqueID), FailedCallback.bind(uniqueID));
```

Then the function would be:

```
function SucceededCallback(result) {
    document.getElementById(this).value = result;
}
```

Or you could use a closure:

```
Webservice1.Foo(param1, function(result) {
    SucceededCallback(result, uniqueID);
}, function(result) {
    FailedCallBack(result, uniqueID);
});
```

Also, instead of passing the ID, you could pass the DOM element itself, so you don't have to call `getElementById`.